# Multi-threading same code at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading, joptionpane, biginteger

I want my program to test two `BigInteger`s at the same time. As of now my code is testing one at a time. Since I want the code to be the same for both runs, is there a simple synchronized statement that I would be able to use to implement this?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number ");
    int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
    BigInteger num = new BigInteger(input);

    String output = num + " is" + (IsPrime(num) ? " " : " not ")
            + "a prime number.";

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
}   
public static boolean IsPrime(BigInteger num) {
    if (num.mod(new BigInteger("2")).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {
      return false;
    for (BigInteger i = new BigInteger("3"); i.multiply(i).compareTo(num) <= 0; i =
        i.add(new BigInteger("2"))) {
      if (num.mod(i).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {
       return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: DO you aim for benchmarking two algorithms or do you simply process something using n parallel threads?

Comment: @Robert using parallel.

Comment: @MatiCicero Then what was the point of your previous comment :) ? Or why did you even bother to search for profile image... Stack Overflow is not social network. We try to focus on problem, not on person. (BTW, to whoever upvoted all posts of OP, serial-upvoting is pointless, such votes will be later removed leaving big `-amount` at OP profile)

Comment: So you can create and start a new `Thread` instances for each BigInteger calling `IsPrime` from the passed `Callable`, but would you want to create a dialog for each?

Comment: @MatiCicero who are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reached a solution to my question.

Because two integers were being tested I needed to create a textOne and a textTwo to test each individually for primeness.

```
 public static boolean IsPrime(BigInteger textOne) {
    // check if number is a multiple of 2
    if (textOne.mod(new BigInteger("2")).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {
      return false;
    }// if not, then just check the odds
    for (BigInteger i = new BigInteger("3"); i.multiply(i).compareTo(textOne) <= 0; i =
        i.add(new BigInteger("2"))) {
      if (textOne.mod(i).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {

       return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
}   
public static boolean IsPrime2(BigInteger textTwo) {
    // check if number is a multiple of 2
    if (textTwo.mod(new BigInteger("2")).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {
      return false;
    }// if not, then just check the odds
    for (BigInteger i = new BigInteger("3"); i.multiply(i).compareTo(textTwo) <= 0; i =
        i.add(new BigInteger("2"))) {
      if (textTwo.mod(i).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {

       return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I designated that num and num2 be designated for the BigIntegers so that output would reflect the following..

```
public void run() {

    String output = num + " is" + (IsPrime(num) ? " " : " not ")
            + "a prime number.";
    lblResults.setText(output);

    String output2 = num2 + " is" + (IsPrime(num2) ? " " : " not ")
            + "a prime number.";
    lblResults2.setText(output2);
}}
```